# Pabot - Test execution continues after closing browser

Tags: python, windows-10, automated-tests, robotframework

I am now successfully running parallel robotframework tests with [Pabot](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot) (if you haven't already, check it out). For the moment, I am running two simple tests at the same time, which consist in performing a login with two different kinds of users. I run my tests from the command line, with the command:

```
pabot --pabotlib --processes 2 --resourcefile valueset.dat --outputdir c:\pabot-demo\reports\ *.robot
```

Everything goes smoothly: the browser opens, the login data is correctly submitted to the form, the post-login homepage appears, and the browser closes. The issue is that, after that, my terminal enters some kind of loop, and the execution doesn't seem to be technically finished:

```
Robot Framework remote server at 127.0.0.1:8270 started.
2018-10-16 15:58:38.109000 [PID:2144] [0] EXECUTING Suites.LoginAdmin
2018-10-16 15:58:38.109000 [PID:9736] [1] EXECUTING Suites.LoginUser

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55688/devtools/browser/9bed6f8e-36c8-40b2-81f5-4622a4933c12

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55689/devtools/browser/074fb0f2-5613-4483-9747-5b98eff98dcd
2018-10-16 15:58:53.853000 [PID:2144] [0] still running Suites.LoginAdmin after 15.0 seconds (next ping in 20.0 seconds)
2018-10-16 15:58:53.953000 [PID:9736] [1] still running Suites.LoginUser after 15.0 seconds (next ping in 20.0 seconds)
2018-10-16 15:59:15.693000 [PID:2144] [0] still running Suites.LoginAdmin after 35.0 seconds (next ping in 25.0 seconds)
2018-10-16 15:59:15.809000 [PID:9736] [1] still running Suites.LoginUser after 35.0 seconds (next ping in 25.0 seconds)
2018-10-16 15:59:43.321000 [PID:2144] [0] still running Suites.LoginAdmin after 60.0 seconds (next ping in 30.0 seconds)
2018-10-16 15:59:43.437000 [PID:9736] [1] still running Suites.LoginUser after 60.0 seconds (next ping in 30.0 seconds)
2018-10-16 16:00:16.330000 [PID:2144] [0] still running Suites.LoginAdmin after 90.0 seconds (next ping in 35.0 seconds)
2018-10-16 16:00:16.415000 [PID:9736] [1] still running Suites.LoginUser after 90.0 seconds (next ping in 35.0 seconds)
2018-10-16 16:00:55.144000 [PID:2144] [0] still running Suites.LoginAdmin after 125.0 seconds (next ping in 40.0 seconds)
2018-10-16 16:00:55.212000 [PID:9736] [1] still running Suites.LoginUser after 125.0 seconds (next ping in 40.0 seconds)
2018-10-16 16:01:39.360000 [PID:2144] [0] still running Suites.LoginAdmin after 165.0 seconds (next ping in 45.0 seconds)
2018-10-16 16:01:39.507000 [PID:9736] [1] still running Suites.LoginUser after 165.0 seconds (next ping in 45.0 seconds)
2018-10-16 16:02:29.098000 [PID:2144] [0] still running Suites.LoginAdmin after 210.0 seconds (next ping in 50.0 seconds)
2018-10-16 16:02:29.445000 [PID:9736] [1] still running Suites.LoginUser after 210.0 seconds (next ping in 50.0 seconds)
2018-10-16 16:02:31.716000 [PID:2144] [0] PASSED Suites.LoginAdmin in 212.3 seconds
2018-10-16 16:02:32.300000 [PID:9736] [1] PASSED Suites.LoginUser in 212.5 seconds
Output:  c:\pabot-demo\reports\output.xml
Log:     c:\pabot-demo\reports\log.html
Report:  c:\pabot-demo\reports\report.html
Stopping PabotLib process
Robot Framework remote server at 127.0.0.1:8270 stopped.
PabotLib process stopped
Elapsed time: 3 minutes 54.904 seconds`
```

This goes on for 3-4 minutes each time, before stopping by its own accord.
My test scenarios are rather simple:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   Tests login functionality
Library         SeleniumLibrary
Library         OperatingSystem
Library         DateTime
Library         Screenshot
Library         pabot.PabotLib
Resource        common.robot
Test Setup      General Setup
Test Teardown   End Scenario

*** Tags ***
Enduser

*** Keywords ***
End Scenario
    Run Keyword If Test Failed  Take Screenshot   01_LoginEnduserTest_FAILED_ScreenShot.png
    Close Browser

General Setup
    # CREATING THE DRIVER VARIABLE
    Set Global Variable     ${DRIVERNAME}   Chrome
    # CREATING THE SCREENSHOT DIRECTORY
    Set Global Variable     ${SCREENSHOTPATH}   [a path]/target/robotframework-reports/${DRIVERNAME}
    Create Directory    ${SCREENSHOTPATH}
    Set Screenshot Directory    ${SCREENSHOTPATH}
    # Getting the valueset
    ${valuesetname}=    Acquire Value Set
    # Opening the browser
    Open Browser    [the application's URL]    Chrome
    Maximize Browser Window
    Location Should Contain     [part of the application's URL]

*** Test Cases ***
Login
    ${username} =   Get Value From Set  username
    ${password} =   Get Value From Set  password
    Input Text      //input[@name='josso_username']     ${username}
    Input Text      //input[@name='josso_password']     ${password}
    Click Element   //input[@type='submit']
    Wait Until Page Contains    Dossier     60
    Location Should Be      [the application's URL]
    Sleep  5s
```

The other scenario is, of course, a variation of this one. After the normal execution, the browser is closed, and I have to wait between 3 and 4 minutes for the ping message to stop and for the reports to be generated, as we can see here:

[image: Robotframework report screenshot]

Having in sight potential future developments (ie, running tests in different machines, to which we presently lack resources), I am using a valueset.dat file to get the different username/password combination. The content of this file is pretty similar to what we see in the Pabot example, but I might as well include it anyway:

```
[Server1]
HOST=(my local IP)
USERNAME=system_admin
PASSWORD=1234

[Server2]
HOST=(my local IP)
USERNAME=system_user
PASSWORD=1234
```

Any idea how to make this long wait go away? Is it possible that, as I add more tests to each suite/more suites, this wait will become irrelevant?

**Edit** I am using the following setup:

- **Python 2.7.14**
- **wxPython 2.8.12.1**, win64, unicode, for py27
- **setuptools 40.2.0** (to allow me to use the easy_install command)
- **Robot Framework 3.0.4**
- **robotremoteserver 1.1**
- **Selenium2Library 3.0.0**
- and **Pabot version 0.45**.

Also, my tests are ran against Chrome, so I'm using **chromedriver 2.41**.

Comment: Can you provide details on your setup: versions for Python, Robot, Pabot, SeleniumLibrary. Does this occur when you run the robot tests manually from the command prompt? If you use a non-browser _Hello World_ type of example with Pabot does this loop also occur? Can you ensure that when you run pabot you refer to a specific file and not *.robot?

Comment: Yes, I edited my post for better visibility, you can check it in the end of my post. Yes, this happens when I run the robot tests manually from the command prompt, with the command I described. Also, apparently. if I remove the "Close Browser" keyword, the loop no longer happens, but in that case, the browser windows remain open, which can't happen...

Comment: Have you tried `Close All Browsers`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both Close Browser and Close All Browser, with and without a 20s Sleep before it (I chose 20s so as to take a larger amount of time than the time it takes to the first ping). The result is the same in all four combinations of these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Test Teardown   Close Browser` at the end of your test suite.